# Tomcat Webapp response gives ????? for special charcters like 'é' UTF-8 encoded string. After every Tomcat restart its working as expected

Tags: java, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding, tomcat8

We have a application deployed on tomcat server v8.5.53 that gives you cookies for User name submitted in Post Request. For normal english characters, this mechanism of base 64 encoding the user info followed by AES encryption in cookies is working fine. But for special charatcer user names like "Amélie.Lacoste", it gets converted to "Am?lie.Lacoste" (if you decrypt decode cookie response).

Strangest thing is that after every restart this response get fixed somehow and we are able to get expected user info from this same application for special character user.

Comment: How do you decrypt cookie response?

Comment: I am using online base64 decode followed with AES decryption and then base 64 decoding.

Comment: So the user sends its name through the form to your server, then you put it to a cookie and then checks the value of that cookie with the next request from client?

Comment: Correct and when that cookie is decoded , we are getting a different user name and its getting rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to explicitly set the charset when encoding and when decoding like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String test = "Amélie.Lacoste";
    String encoded = Base64.toBase64String(test.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(new String(Base64.decode(encoded), "UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: I have already explicitly defined charset while encoding and when decoding. I highly doubt this is a coding issue but more of tomcat configuration issue as tomcat server retsarts solves this problem and everything works fine.

Comment: Setting file encoding in tomcat catalina.sh fixed this for me.

Comment: Okay, Why do you think the issue didn't reproduce some tie after restart (before fix)?

Answer (score 0):

Setting file.encoding to utf-8 in tomcat catalina.sh solved this for me.

```
**JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"**
```

Comment: If that solves your problem, you are likely using `new String(bytes)` without explicitly specifying the character set, use `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead, or you're using `String.getBytes()` instead of `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` when creating the cookie value.